# How to determine if an item can be moved to a certain position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def can_item_move_to(self, item_position, item_target):
```

---

I want to return a `boolean` where it is True if the item can move to the target position, False otherwise.

This function is part of a class where

**They are multiple conditions:**

1. It can only move diagonally
2. If `item` is type man and color white it can only move upwards, if it's black only downward
3. A lady type piece can advance on any diagonal, regardless of its color.

I figure the solution would be to use `multiple if statements`, but I am not sure such as:

```
if item_position == item_target:
    return False:
elif item_position == (identify as lady):
   #verify if it's moving diagonally
```

It's only a few condition, but it seems to involve lots of `if statements` which I am not sure how to implement.

Comment: If `position` and `target` are integers, how do you know which `Position`s they correspond to?

Comment: My strategy would be: There are two problems here: 1. check if a move is legal 2. check if the target of a move is blocked. Regarding 1.: given position=x,y notice that a move was diagonal iff  x+y or x-y did not change. Then you need to check wether x or y exceeds the board limits, finally check depending on figure  type if x changed at most by one and y increased/decreased at most by 1. Regarding 2: If it’s a man, look up wether the target is already occupied, if it’s a lady, assemble a move from many man moves.

Comment: @Samwise oh i meant target and position is composed of two integer such as (3,5), (1,0)

Comment: Oh, just noticed that assembling a lady move from many man moves is a terrible idea. But break up you Code with functions like ‘check_diagonal(piece, target)’, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work your way down the list:

```
def can_item_move_to(self, item_position, item_target):
    dx, dy = item_target[0] - item_position[0], item_target[1] - item_position[1]
    item = self.cases.get(item_position)
    return (
        # dx, dy must be a diagonal
        abs(dx) == abs(dy)
        # Not moving downwards if it's a white man
        and not(item == Item("white", "man") and dy < 0)
        # Not moving upwards if it's a black man
        and not(item == Item("black", "man") and dy > 0)
        # No item at target position
        and not item_target in self.cases
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, what would be an example of a  unit test such as assert == True or False

Comment: and what does this line do     item = self.cases.get(item_position)